# Visual Studio Mac Intellisense produce new line instead of complete the text when pressing return

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio

I am using VS Mac 7.7.2 Build: 21 with Unity3d. The following happen when trying to use IntelliSense:

IntelliSense suggest "_card" after I typed "_ca":

[image]

I press return:

[image]

And IntelliSense do not complete the property name but instead create a new line without completing the propert name.

This have started after I updated VS.

Anyone familiar with this problem and have a solution?

**>>>>>>>>>> SOLVED <<<<<<<<<<**

Problem solved, for me, in Visual Studio 7.7.3 Build:43.

Comment: I have VS Mac 7.6.8 (build 38) and intellisense working as expected. It looks like yours isnt highlighted. What happens when you press tab?

Comment: It worked for me as well until this version. I bought a new laptop an d reinstalled and got this version.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known, but still not fully resolved bug: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/41831/c-autocomplete-enter-inserts-new-line-instead.html

Answer (score -2):

That is how Visual Studio for Mac is working. It is product bought by Microsoft and it doesn't necessary have to be compatible with Visual Studio for Windows practices as much of it was made before Microsoft took over.

Comment: I have had no problem with this in previous versions.